# Where do the error message come from this piece of code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Intro all this code is from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Message in question:

```
1 error prohibited this article from being saved:

Title is too short (minimum is 5 characters)
```

Code part 1 defining parameters

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

Code part 2 error message

```
<% if @article.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
      this article from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The error messages are coming from a combination of your controller and model.

```
def new
  @article = Article.new
end

def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)

  if @article.save # the magic happens here
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
end
```

When you call @article.save, you're asking your model 'does this new article have a title with a length of at least 5 characters?'. If yes, the Article will be saved to the database and you will be redirected to @article.

```
if @article.save
  redirect_to @article
```

If not it will re-render the new page (render 'new') with the @articles.errors.messages

```
else
  render 'new'
end
```

Making your article model the instance variable @article allows you to carry whatever data/methods that model has into the view. In this case you can carry your error messages into your new form. Your new form's code here detects if @article has an errors, which is to say if calling @article.errors.any? returns an array of messages greater than 0.

```
<% if @article.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
      this article from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

So in your case you had a title that was too short. This block of code takes that single error, uses the pluralize magic for your h2 tag's message and then lists each error in the @articles.errors.full_messages.each block.

Comment: My bad, I know why it's showing an error, it was on porpuse, what I don't know is where is coming from this string :"Title is too short (minimum is 5 characters)" I can't find it's origin.

Comment: @luigi An error message is always generated for each validation, and in some cases for each options hash you pass a validation. When you typed in a blank field for title you should receive two error messages, the first saying "title can't be blank" and the second being "Title is too short (minimum is 5 characters)". If you changed your minimum setting to 7 the message should change to "minimum is 7 characters."

In other words, those error messages are magically generated for each validation you have for your model.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, Article is an ActiveRecord object. This means it inherits certain actions (abilities). In this case, when the submitted title does not meet the 'validates' line in the code part 1, it adds an errors action to the Article.

After, in part 2 of your code, the 'full_messages' action is being called on the errors I already mentioned. That is where the message you're asking about comes from. Try it in the rails console and try to save an object that doesn't pass validations. Then call the @article.errors.full_messages action on it and take a look.

To expand a bit more, the 'errors' here would be ActiveRecord error objects. The full_messages is pretty much an array which contains the text of each error (e.g. "Title is too short."